# Flickity: Trigger a "dot" click from another element via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, flickity

I'm trying to trigger a click on one of the navigation dots from another DOM element, but I can't seem to do it a la the following:

```
$('li.dot')[0].click();
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you doing this on page load? Probably your element is not ready yet.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: Sorry I don't usually use jQuery. I forgot you need to use first, or first-child, or something of the type to get the node from the jQuery object, not use el[0].

```
$('li.dot').first().trigger('click');
```

Comment: You know you can do `$(li.dot:first')` right? 
and when `.click()` is called without arguments, it is a shortcut for `.trigger("click")`.

Comment: I changed my answer, as I realized right as you were voting. I don't use jQuery as often any more. :)